# GUEST MEM - VMWARE

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, virtualhost, virtual-machines, memory-usage

I am reviewing an esxi 4.1 host memory usage I would like to lower some of the memory usage on some virtual machines.

For example here I have a windows 2003 server [image: Windows 2003 server]

This server is using 1GB Ram one more than it needs, I want to have a lean environment for the ESXI hosts.

Does lowering the vm ram lower the amount of ram being used by the host.

As here it is displaying consumed host memory, its very confusing.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't see an question here anywhere. What do you want to know?

Comment: I'm confused - you know giving a VM `x`GB of memory doesn't actually reserve it or anything if it's not using it? I.e., you can set all your VM's too 20GB of RAM if you like. The problems only come when the machines want that RAM! Plus, you should be looking at the vSphere resource monitor, not Windows.

Comment: "I want to have a lean environment for the ESXI hosts" is ill-defined and ill-conceived and is tantamount to "busy work" in my opinion.

Comment: You still haven't asked a question, @JJJJNR...

Comment: I agree, im fairly new to vmware, so im comparing hardware environments to virtual, and apologies if I come across that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Does lowering the vm ram lower the amount of ram being used by the host."

No. Not if the RAM isn't being used by the guest OS.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, time to read some VMware notes.